# How to let Guice bind an annotated injection to a single instance

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have an UI component that will be used in several UI module in an application.

I would like to annotate the UI component that to be injected into several other classes in one UI module to be a singleton, but not a singleton across the whole application. So that for each UI module use the UI component, one and only one of the UI component instance is used.

I couldn't find a straight solution for this from the Guice document. So i think maybe I can use annotation to distinguish those instance? 
Say in Module A, I annotate all the injection of the UI component with `Named("ModuleA")`; and in Module B, with `Named("ModulaB")`. and in the configuration, i tried to use something like:

```
this.bind(UIComponentA.class)
    .annotatedWith(Names.named("ModulaA"))
    .to(UIComponentAImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);

this.bind(UIComponentA.class)
    .annotatedWith(Names.named("ModulaB"))
    .to(UIComponentAImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

Because UICompoenetAImpl also need to be injected, so I couldn't simply create the instance there. Totally not sure if this works.

And I'm wondering what's the standard way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other option might be to use a [child injector](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#createChildInjector%28com.google.inject.Module...%29) for each module.

This would allow you to bind a difference instance of `UIComponentA` in each module. Bind them in the child injector rather than the parent. You would then need to make sure that all of your module's dependencies are built from the right child injector, probably by making sure the root of each module is loaded from the right place.

Answer (score 0):

> > Because UICompoenetAImpl also need to be injected, so I couldn't simply create the instance there.

I think you can just create UIComponentAImpl there and bind toInstance. When you do so - other beans will be injected in UIComponentAImpl. Please see my example [here](http://moradanen.sopovs.com/2011/10/inject-in-toinstance-binding.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but As i said the UICompoenentAImpl also has dependencies and need to be injected by Guice.

Comment: Have you checked that these dependencies are not injected if you create UICompoenentAImpl manually and add it to guice container via bind(...).toInstance()? What kind of dependencies?

Comment: Unfortunately It has several dependencies which also need to be injected by Guice. it will be quite cumbersome to manually create the instance.

Comment: Please, please, please read my answer! You don't need to manually pass dependencies to manually created instance of bean. They are set by guice when you add instance to guice container with bind(..).toInstance() method. Read the example through the link.

Comment: Basically you said - "I cannot do A because...". My reply is - "You _can_ do A because ...". Give please a little attention to the "because" part of my answer and give a bit more detail to your "because" if it is inaccurate.

Comment: ok. thanks, i got the point now. u were using filed injection and i was using constructor injection. that's why i thought i couldn't create the instance manually. The behaviour do look a bit wire though.